# Como aplicar uma mesma condição/operação para cada elemento de um vetor em C

Tags: c, array, lista, algoritmo, condição

Oi, pessoal!

Eu preciso realizar uma mesma operação para todos os elementos de um dado vetor. Como fazer isso?

Mais especificamente, eu preciso verificar se um elemento qualquer "x" tem, nas suas duas posições adjacentes maiores que x, um número que seja igual a x+1 ou x+2. E, no caso, eu preciso verificar se essa mesma condição é válida para os outros elementos em posições maiores que vetor[x] (ou seja, preciso aplicar isso para "x" e para os n valores nas posições maiores que a de "x").

Para facilitar o entendimento, vou exemplificar. Suponha que temos a seguinte entrada:

> 1 2 4 5 6 8 9 12

Para esse caso, suponha que x=4.

O meu código precisa fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

5 = 4+1 ou 4+2? Sim.

6 = 4+1 ou 4+2? Sim.

6 = 5+1 ou 5+2? Sim.

8 = 5+1 ou 5+2? Não.

8 = 6+1 ou 6+2? Sim.

9 = 6+1 ou 6+2? Não.

9 = 8+1 ou 8+2? Sim.

12 = 8+1 ou 8+2? Não.

12 = 9+1 ou 9+2? Não.

E aí o programa para depois de ter feito todas essas verificações para os elementos iguais ou maiores que x. E aí o programa deveria mostrar na tela todos os casos "sim".

Consegui fazer isso para x, mas eu não tenho ideia de como fazer para os outros casos que preciso. Eu gostaria de ter pelo menos alguma noção do que eu posso tentar...

Pensei em fazer o que eu quero em um vetor e passar os elementos selecionados para um outro vetor, e aí mostrar na tela. Mas eu não sei como fazer isso... Acho que primeiro eu precisaria manipular os elementos maiores que "x", mas como?

Por enquanto, tentei isso em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int verifica_proximas_posicoes(int i, int x) {
    if((i == x + 1) || (i == x + 2)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){

    int i, numero, vetor[8], vetor1[8];

    printf("Escreva todos os elementos do vetor:\n");
    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }
    printf("Escreva o número que deseja:\n");
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    for(i=numero; i<=8; i++){
        if(verifica_proximas_posicoes(i+1, numero)){
            vetor1[i] = vetor[i];
            printf("%d ", vetor1[i]);
        }
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Creio que esta sua dedução: "E, no caso, eu preciso verificar se essa mesma condição é válida para os outros elementos em posições maiores que vetor[x] (ou seja, preciso aplicar isso para "x" e para os n valores nas posições maiores que a de "x")." está errada. Me parece que você deve procurar "x" no vetor e, caso encontre, verificar se as duas posições adjacentes atendem à condição. Suponha que o valor "x" exista na posição "i", neste caso você tem que verificar se vetor[i+1] ou vetor[i+2] atendem a condição.

Comment: Seria de grande valia se você colocasse o problema original

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que este código pode te ajudar a entender melhor como você pode chegar na solução para o seu problema.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  // Estas variáveis foram declaradas estaticamente com a finalidade de
  // explicar melhor o funcionamento do programa por si só, mas acredito
  // que você pode ler essas variáveis dinamicamente na sua implementação
  int index_of_x = 2, x = 4, vetor_inicial[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12},
      tamanho_do_vetor = 8;

  for (int i = index_of_x + 1; i < tamanho_do_vetor; i++, x++) {
    if (vetor_inicial[i] == x + 1 || vetor_inicial[i] == x + 2) {
      printf("%d = %d+1 ou %d+2? Sim.\n", vetor_inicial[i], x, x);
    } else
      printf("%d = %d+1 ou %d+2? Não.\n", vetor_inicial[i], x, x);

    // Para evitar que o programa leia dados inválidos.
    if (i + 1 == tamanho_do_vetor) break;

    if (vetor_inicial[i + 1] == x + 1 || vetor_inicial[i + 1] == x + 2) {
      printf("%d = %d+1 ou %d+2? Sim.\n", vetor_inicial[i + 1], x, x);
    } else
      printf("%d = %d+1 ou %d+2? Não.\n", vetor_inicial[i + 1], x, x);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Este código produziu o seguinte resultado:

```
5 = 4+1 ou 4+2? Sim.
6 = 4+1 ou 4+2? Sim.
6 = 5+1 ou 5+2? Sim.
8 = 5+1 ou 5+2? Não.
8 = 6+1 ou 6+2? Sim.
9 = 6+1 ou 6+2? Não.
9 = 7+1 ou 7+2? Sim.
12 = 7+1 ou 7+2? Não.
12 = 8+1 ou 8+2? Não.
```